# Proving that the exterior algebra of a free module is free via universal property

Tags: exterior-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $M$ be a free $R$-module with basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. If $I=\{i_1,\ldots,i_k\}, i_1<i_2\cdots<i_k$,  is a subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $e_I=e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_k}$.

It is known that the exterior algebra $\Lambda M$ is free as an $R$-module, with basis $(e_I)_I$.

Most of the proofs I know to get this fact use one of the following approaches:

- Prove that $\Lambda^k M$ is free by showing that the family $(e_I)_I$ is linearly independent over $R$, using determinant-like alternating maps + the universal property of $\Lambda^k M$ (like in [Keith's Conrad paper](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf))
- Prove  that $\Lambda M$ is free by  exhibiting a basis of the ideal of the tensor algebra $T(M)$ generated by the elements $x\otimes x, x\in M$, using careful inspection (like in [these notes](http://therisingsea.org/notes/TensorExteriorSymmetric.pdf))
- Use the canonical isomorphism $\Lambda(M\oplus N)\simeq \Lambda M\widehat{\otimes} \Lambda N$

**Question.** Do you know any proof of the fact that $\Lambda M$ is free whenever $M$ is free,  which relies only the universal property of $\Lambda M$ ?

Of course, the third approach uses  a result which is proved using the universal property, but this result is quite strong to prove such a thing...

For the record, the universal property i'm talking about is: any map $f:M\to C$ ($C$ is unital associative) such that $f(x)^2=0$ for all $x\in M$ extends in a unique way to a map $\Lambda M \to C$.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you would consider to be using "only the universal property of $\Lambda M$".  Of course you can just construct an explicit model of $\Lambda M$ which has a given basis and then prove that it has the universal property.

Comment: But that is what all the other proofs you mention do, one way or another (indeed, it is in some sense the only way you can hope to prove it, since the existence of such an explicit model follows immediately from the result).  So it's really not clear to me what you want.